# Dúvida com select em if

Tags: php, select, if

Boa tarde

Eu estava tentando adaptar um código que já tinha aqui para poder por uma marca d'água em uma foto. Mas tem bastante tempo que não mexo com html e nem php. Por isso, vocês poderiam me dar essa ajuda para arrumar o problema de selecionar o .png correto (marca d'água) e até em reformular o código para ficar mais simplificado ?

```
<script src="http://deepliquid.com/Jcrop/js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo_files/demos.css" type="text/css" />
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['cor']) == "preto") {
          $image_path = "avatares/preto.png";
    } elseif (isset($_POST['cor']) == "branco") {
        $image_path = "avatares/branco.png";
    } elseif (isset($_POST['cor']) == "colorido") {
        $image_path = "avatares/colorido.png";
    } else {
        echo ":)";
    }

function watermark_image($oldimage_name, $new_image_name){
    global $image_path;
    list($owidth,$oheight) = getimagesize($oldimage_name);
    $width  = 800;
    $height = 800;    
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $img_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($oldimage_name);
    imagecopyresampled($im, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $owidth, $oheight);
    $watermark = imagecreatefrompng($image_path);
    list($w_width, $w_height) = getimagesize($image_path);        
    $pos_x = $width - $w_width; 
    $pos_y = $height - $w_height;
    imagecopy($im, $watermark, $pos_x, $pos_y, 0, 0, $w_width, $w_height);
    imagejpeg($im, $new_image_name, 100);
    imagedestroy($im);
    unlink($oldimage_name);
    return true;
}

$demo_image= "";
if(isset($_POST['createmark']) and $_POST['createmark'] == "Submit"){
    $path = "uploads/";
    $valid_formats = array("jpg","bmp","jpeg");
    $name = $_FILES['imgfile']['name'];
    if(strlen($name))
{
   list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
   if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)&& $_FILES['imgfile']['size'] <= 10*256*1024)
    {
    $upload_status = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imgfile']['tmp_name'], $path.$_FILES['imgfile']['name']);
    if($upload_status){
        $new_name = $path.time().".jpg";
        if(watermark_image($path.$_FILES['imgfile']['name'], $new_name))
                $demo_image = $new_name;

    }
    }
    else
    $msg = "A foto tem que ter menos que 2,5mb.";
    }
}

    # Conta quantos arquivos existem na pasta de upload
    $diretorio = scandir("uploads/");
    $qtd = count($diretorio) - 2;

?>
    <html lang="pt-br">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Avatarizador</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/avatar.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> </head>

    <body>
        <div id="conteudo">
            <form name="imageUpload" id="imageUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
                <h1>Avatarizador !</h1>
                <div class="giro">V 2.0</div>
                <p class="texto">Já foram criadas <strong><?PHP echo ("$qtd"); ?></strong> fotos com o avatar do EREA Salvador.</p>
                <input style="margin-bottom:15px;" type="file" name="imgfile" id="imgfile" />
                <select name="cor">
                    <option value="preto">Preto</option>
                    <option value="branco">Branco</option>
                    <option value="colorido">Colorido</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="createmark" id="createmark" value="Submit" />
                <br>
                <?php
                    if(!empty($demo_image)){
                        echo '
                            <center>
                                <b>Click na imagem para fazer o download.</b>
                                <br><br>
                                <a href="'.$demo_image.'" download>
                                <img id="avatar" src="'.$demo_image.'" />
                                </a>
                            </center>
                            ';

                        $arquivo = "rastro.txt";
                        date_default_timezone_set('America/Bahia');
                        $data = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', time());
                        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];    
                        $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
                        $fp = fopen($arquivo, "a+");   
                        fwrite($fp,"Arquivo: $new_name | Data: $data | IP: $ip | Navegador: $browser \n\r");   
                        fclose($fp);

                    }
                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Para quem quiser saber como o código está se comportando agora, basta acessar:
http://ereasalvador.com.br/avatar/index.php

Comment: Qual é o problema com relação a marca d'água?

Comment: Sempre que seleciono uma das cores, o script acaba trabalhando apenas com o avatar de cor preta, no caso, o primeiro

Answer (score 1):

Caros, desculpem mas já cheguei a uma solução, utilizando um switch :D

O resultado ficou assim:

```
<script src="http://deepliquid.com/Jcrop/js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo_files/demos.css" type="text/css" />
<?php

switch($_POST['cor']){
    case 'preto' : 
        $image_path = "avatares/preto.png";
        break;
    case 'branco':
        $image_path = "avatares/branco.png";
        break;
    case 'colorido':
        $image_path = "avatares/colorido.png";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Eita, deu erro";
}


function watermark_image($oldimage_name, $new_image_name){
    global $image_path;
    list($owidth,$oheight) = getimagesize($oldimage_name);
    $width  = 800;
    $height = 800;    
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $img_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($oldimage_name);
    imagecopyresampled($im, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $owidth, $oheight);
    $watermark = imagecreatefrompng($image_path);
    list($w_width, $w_height) = getimagesize($image_path);        
    $pos_x = $width - $w_width; 
    $pos_y = $height - $w_height;
    imagecopy($im, $watermark, $pos_x, $pos_y, 0, 0, $w_width, $w_height);
    imagejpeg($im, $new_image_name, 100);
    imagedestroy($im);
    unlink($oldimage_name);
    return true;
}

$demo_image= "";
if(isset($_POST['createmark']) and $_POST['createmark'] == "Submit"){
    $path = "uploads/";
    $valid_formats = array("jpg","bmp","jpeg");
    $name = $_FILES['imgfile']['name'];
    if(strlen($name))
{
   list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
   if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)&& $_FILES['imgfile']['size'] <= 10*256*1024)
    {
    $upload_status = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imgfile']['tmp_name'], $path.$_FILES['imgfile']['name']);
    if($upload_status){
        $new_name = $path.time().".jpg";
        if(watermark_image($path.$_FILES['imgfile']['name'], $new_name))
                $demo_image = $new_name;

    }
    }
    else
    $msg = "A foto tem que ter menos que 2,5mb.";
    }
}

    # Conta quantos arquivos existem na pasta de upload
    $diretorio = scandir("uploads/");
    $qtd = count($diretorio) - 2;

?>
    <html lang="pt-br">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Avatarizador</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/avatar.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> </head>

    <body>
        <div id="conteudo">
            <form name="imageUpload" id="imageUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
                <h1>Avatarizador !</h1>
                <div class="giro">V 2.0</div>
                <p class="texto">Já foram criadas <strong><?PHP echo ("$qtd"); ?></strong> fotos com o avatar do EREA Salvador.</p>
                <input style="margin-bottom:15px;" type="file" name="imgfile" id="imgfile" />
                <select name="cor">
                    <option value="preto">Preto</option>
                    <option value="branco">Branco</option>
                    <option value="colorido">Colorido</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="createmark" id="createmark" value="Submit" />
                <br>
                <?php
                    if(!empty($demo_image)){
                        echo '
                            <center>
                                <b>Click na imagem para fazer o download.</b>
                                <br><br>
                                <a href="'.$demo_image.'" download>
                                <img id="avatar" src="'.$demo_image.'" />
                                </a>
                            </center>
                            ';

                        $arquivo = "rastro.txt";
                        date_default_timezone_set('America/Bahia');
                        $data = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', time());
                        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];    
                        $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
                        $fp = fopen($arquivo, "a+");   
                        fwrite($fp,"Arquivo: $new_name | Data: $data | IP: $ip | Navegador: $browser \n\r");   
                        fclose($fp);

                    }
                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Sim, entendi. No código original você fez uma comparação de isset (boolean) com "preto" (string). O javascript estava convertendo o string "preto" para booleano, assim sendo, qualquer valor diferente de "" (vazio ou nulo) é considerado verdadeiro, por isso ele sempre retornava o preto.

Answer (score 1):

Você fez uma pequena confusão ao usar a função "isset()". Ela verifica se a variável já foi definida e o resultado é booleano (verdadeiro ou falso).

Imagino que você queira o seguinte:

```js
if(isset($_POST['cor']) {
    switch ($_POST['cor']) {
        case 'preto':
            $image_path = "avatares/preto.png";
            break;
        case 'branco':
            $image_path = "avatares/branco.png";
            break;
        case 'colorido':
            $image_path = "avatares/colorido.png";
            break;
        default:
            echo ":)";
    }
}
```